# Decompress Tile Package

Tags: arcgis-10.1, cache, tile-package

I'm curious if it's possible to decompress a 10.1 **[tile package (.tpk)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000457000000)** into a different format such as the cache bundle format.

Answer (score 2):

Tile packages are just normal zip files which contain the images in a "bundle" format along with metadata in more familiar formats.

The bundle format is proprietary and undocumented.  Some details including initial code sample are available on the [ArcGIS forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57239-Compact-Cache-Bundle-Format).